# Width of div taking all remaining width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to put a top bar on the right of my left menu.
I put `width: 100%` of my `#top_bar` but there is so big. I would like that my top bar take only the remaining space of the screen.

**HTML:**

```
<body>    
    <div id="menu_left"></div>
    <div id="top_bar"></div>      
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
#menu_left {
    background-color: #354052;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}

#top_bar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EFF0F3;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    left: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Result:**
[image]

Comment: `width: calc(100% - 200px);` http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: The page width becomes 100% + 200px, that is why the horizontal scroll bar appears. Is there any strong constraint for the menu-left, that it must be exactly 200px?

Comment: @cezar Yes, the size of left menu must stay on 200px

Comment: @wawanopoulos Ok, the solution has been already posted. When asking for the width of menu-left I was thinking of responsive design. WIdth of 200px would be to much for a smartphone with 640x480 resolution.

Comment: @cezar You are right.. What is the solution for the width of my left menu ?

Comment: The solution has been posted by @A.Wolff in the first comment. If you want to make it responsive than it would be a little bit more complicated.

Comment: @wawanopoulos You should set your menu left menu in relative unit too, as %. But on some device as mobile, could bring some other issues. To get a better responsiv design, you'd have better to use a front-end framework as e.g twitter bootstrap

Comment: @cezar I have to use media queries ?

Comment: @wawanopoulos Ya, you could use media queries, that's basically how work responsiv design

Comment: @wawanopoulos Yes, you have to use media queries, if you want to make it responsive, as 200px may be fine for laptop, but would be to much for a smartphone or would look to narrow on a big 24 inch screen. As A.Wolff suggested you can use a front-end framework (Bootstrap, Foundation, YAML4 or some other).

Comment: @wawanopoulos have you seen the answers?

Answer (score 1):

```
#top_bar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EFF0F3;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    top: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the margin left for the large div

CSS :

```
#menu_left {
    background-color: #354052;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
} 
#top_bar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EFF0F3;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 200px;
    height: 70px;
}
```

HTML :

```
<body>
    <div id="menu_left"></div>
    <div id="top_bar"></div>
</body>
```

Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/patelmit69/yce07ph4/)

Comment: I don't think it is what OP is looking for but could give him idea how to redesign completly its site

Comment: This will work, but it is not responsive and on small screens like smartphones would just make a bad impression.

Comment: You can use the width and margin by % then it will work in responsive also

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your css:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/420wwopu/)? You could only change `width: 100%` to `right: 0`. Also `float: left` is unnecessary.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;    
}

#menu_left {
    background-color: #354052;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}

#top_bar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EFF0F3;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
    height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_left"></div>
<div id="top_bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a 100% width container around your elements.

```
<div class="container">

    <div id="menu_left">
    </div>

    <div id="top_bar">
       NAVIGATION
    </div>

</div>
```

See this pen I just created: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwodLx